# Parse.com For Social Networking

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I am about to write a social networking android app using parse.com because am not really a database guy, but am also scared because facebook has acquired parse.com, what if my app becomes a hit will facebook kill it and if yes, please what other backend do you suggest i use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They cant kill it When you are using the legal source ...
Another is cloud9